# How to assign "all groups" permission with Azure WebPubSubServiceClient.GetClientAccessUri?

Tags: c#, azure-web-pubsub

The `Azure.Messaging.WebPubSub.Clients` SDK allows us to create an Azure PubSub *service* client like this:

```
var serviceClient = new WebPubSubServiceClient(<connectionstring>, "hubName");
```

Using this client we can generate temporary tokens with with which to open up a *websocket* client, like this:

```
var url = client.GetClientAccessUri(roles: new string[]
    { $"webpubsub.sendToGroup.mygroup", $"webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.mygroup" }).AbsoluteUri;
var wsClient = new WebPubSubClient(new Uri(url));
```

The above code has initialised a websocket client that has the permission to join the "mygroup" group, and also to send to that group. The below for example would work

```
wsClient.GroupMessageReceived += eventArgs =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Receive group message from {eventArgs.Message.Group}: {eventArgs.Message.Data}");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
await wsClient.StartAsync();
await wsClient.JoinGroupAsync("mygroup");
```

What I am looking for is a way to do grant permission to *all* groups in the hub. I have not been able to find any documentation on this, but since "sendToAll" is a well-defined concept in Azure PubSub I would be surprised if this didn't exist.

The following does not work:

```
var url = client.GetClientAccessUri(roles: new string[]
    { $"webpubsub.sendToGroup.*", $"webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.*" }).AbsoluteUri;
```

Nethier does this:

```
var url = client.GetClientAccessUri(roles: new string[]
    { $"webpubsub.sendToAll", $"webpubsub.joinLeaveAll" }).AbsoluteUri;
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across the answer while looking for something else this morning, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/concept-service-internals#authentication-workflow

The below will allow joining any group and sending to all groups:

```
var url = client.GetClientAccessUri(roles: new string[]
    { $"webpubsub.sendToGroup", $"webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup" }).AbsoluteUri;
```